# R Shiny: Convert text with multiple URLs to individually clickable URLs in datatable

Tags: r, shiny

I've a dataframe of texts that contain urls that looks like this:

```
df=data.frame(Text=c("Great weather today at the course, early tee off https://www.uspgatour.co.uk","Pizzas are my favorite here https://www.dinospizza.com and here https://www.mariospizza.com"))
```

I tried to extract the URLs from each text and store them in a new column `URL`

```
library(qdapRegex)
df$URL=rm_url(df$Text, extract=TRUE)
```

For the first row that contains just one URL, it has extracted it and stored it in the column.

However in the row that contains two URLs, the result is stored as:

> c("https://www.dinospizza.com", "https://www.mariospizza.com")

Unlike a single URL, the above result is unclickable in a datatable, as Shiny treats it as a single URL, even though it is actually two combined.

**I am looking for a way to split each URL ,so that each is treated as a separate link that can be clicked on for the same row.**

Here is the part of my code in `server.R` that converts text to clickable URL

```
# Convert table to final

global_summary =reactive({

global_summarised=results_combined %>%
  filter(SVM_PROB_QOL >=input$inp_pg1qolproba & globalsegment==input$inp_pg1segment & Date >=input$inp_pg1daterange[1] & Date <=input$inp_pg1daterange[2]) %>%
  select(SVM_LABEL_QOL,SVM_LABEL_DIMENSION,globalsegment,Segment,Account,Date,text,Type,URL) %>%
  filter(!is.na(SVM_LABEL_QOL) & SVM_LABEL_QOL=='QoL' & !duplicated(text)) %>% #precautionary
  group_by(globalsegment,SVM_LABEL_DIMENSION) %>%
  top_n(1000,Date) %>%
  arrange(desc(Date))

#Some cleaning up using pre-defined functions

global_summarised$text=clean_text_proper(global_summarised$text)
global_summarised=relabel_globalsegments(global_summarised)
global_summarised=relabel_subsegments(global_summarised)
names(global_summarised)=c("Classified","Dimension","Global Segment","Sub-Segment","Client","Created","QoL Tweet","Tweet Type","URL")

#Make URLs clickable
global_summarised$URL <- ifelse(!is.na(global_summarised$URL),paste0("<a href='",global_summarised$URL,"'>",global_summarised$URL,"</a>"),"")


global_summarised

})

#And then render table using reactive expression

output$global_summarised_table <- renderDataTable(datatable(global_summary(),options=list(pageLength=5),escape = FALSE))
```

Any advice on how to break up a vector of URLs in Shiny, so each one can be treated as a separate URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could do

```
library(DT)
df <- data.frame(URL = I(list(c("https://www.dinospizza.com", "https://www.mariospizza.com"))))
df$URL <- sapply(df$URL, function(x) paste(sprintf('<a href="%1$s">%1$s</a>', x), collapse=","))
datatable(df,options=list(pageLength=5),escape = FALSE)
```